# Set color to output from verbatim

Tags: color, verbatim

I want to show the output from `verbatim` in blue color.

I have this:

```
\newcommand{\blockcode}[1]{\ttfamily\small#1}

{\blockcode \begin{verbatim} 
alias vi="vim"
\end{verbatim}}
```

which works fine.

But when I do this

```
\newcommand{\blockcode}[1]{\ttfamily\small{\color{blue}#1}}
```

it throws an error

> ! Argument of \begin has an
>   extra }.

**Update**

I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim,color,lipsum}

\newcommand{\blockcode}{\ttfamily\small\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
{\blockcode \begin{verbatim} 
alias vi="vim"
\end{verbatim}}

\lipsum*[3]
\end{document}
```

But the blockcode doesn't end... it flows on to the next element...

**Update 2**

If I do this:

```
\paragraph{Hello}
\begin{blockcode}
alias vi="vim"
\end{blockcode}
```

The `Hello` also becomes blue in color. Any way I can stop this?

**Update 3**

Again a roadblock...

```
\subsubsection*{Definition}
\begin{blockcode} 
:iabbrev <key> <expansion> 
\end{blockcode}
```

This creates too much gap between `Definition` and the code.

Comment: Don't give `\blockcode` an argument. `\newcommand{\blockcode}{\ttfamily\small\color{blue}}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a number of better alternatives.

**First.** Package `verbatim`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim,color,lipsum}
\newenvironment{blockcode}
  {\leavevmode\small\color{blue}\verbatim}
  {\endverbatim}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{blockcode}
alias vi="vim"
\end{blockcode}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{document}
```

Pros: easy. Cons: not really customizable.

**Second.** Package `fancyvrb`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,color,lipsum}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{blockcode}
  {Verbatim}
  {fontsize=\small,formatcom=\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{blockcode}
alias vi="vim"
\end{blockcode}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{document}
```

Pros: very customizable. Cons: less easy to learn how to manage the definitions.

**Third.** Package `listings`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,color,lipsum}

\lstnewenvironment{blockcode}[1][]
  {\lstset{language=Bash,
           columns=fullflexible,
           basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
           keywordstyle=\color{blue},
   }}
  {}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{blockcode}
alias vi="vim"
\end{blockcode}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{document}
```

Pros: keyword coloring for the supported languages. Cons: doesn't support UTF-8

Comment: What does lipsum do?

Comment: Just try it: it provides mock text for filling examples.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, although this wasn't my exact question...

Comment: @ATOzTOA David will surely say that I always answer the question that should have been asked.

Comment: Please see my Update 2.

Comment: @ATOzTOA Use the method with `fancyvrb` or add `\leavevmode` before `\small` in the first method. I'll update.

Comment: It worked! But I have another issue now, please see Update 3.

Comment: @ATOzTOA Use method 2, with `fancyvrb`. Didn't I say that already? :)

Comment: When I don't use `\leavevmode` with `subsubsection`, it works fine.

Comment: New environment is highly uncentered in beamer. Any tips?

Comment: Added my own answer

Answer (score 8):

```
\newcommand{\blockcode}[1]{\ttfamily\small#1}

{\blockcode \begin{verbatim} 
alias vi="vim"
\end{verbatim}}
```

Only really works by accident. the argument to `\blockcode` is (just) `\begin` so `\begin` is removed from its argument `{verbatim}` but as `#` is replaced at the end of the definition, `\begin` is put back and it works out OK,

Once you use

```
\newcommand{\blockcode}[1]{\ttfamily\small{\color{blue}#1}}
```

Then the expansion is

```
\ttfamily\small{\color{blue}\begin}
```

So the first thing `\begin` sees is a closing brace and things go wrong.

Just use

```
\newcommand{\blockcode}{\ttfamily\small\color{blue}}
```

Note that you should always end a font size change command in vertical mode

```
{\small aaaa\par}
```

not

```
{\small aaa}\par
```

otherwise the line spacing will be wrong. In this case you are OK as `verbatim` is a list environment so ends the paragraph.

Also as noted in `grfguide` using a `\color` command before the list will adversely affect the spacing (it's not my fault). In this case as you are changing teh size anyway thi sisn't perhaps too much of an issue.

Comment: This is not working, the verbatim doesn't stop at `\end{verbatim}`. Please see the updated question.

Comment: You included the verbatim package which has the documented restriction that you can not have anything on the line after `\end{verbatim}` so you would have to move that last `}` down a line, which just shows: always post complete documents in questions not fragments

Comment: Yeah, it works now... thanks... But, that last brace is already included in my question... oh yeah, now I understand what you mean :)

Answer (score 1):

**For Beamer users**:

This code creates a new environment (`myverbatim`) with specific colour (`\blue`) and font size (`\small`), as in the example:

```
\newenvironment{myverbatim}
{\semiverbatim\small\color{blue}}
{\endsemiverbatim}
```

You can also redefine the main `verbatim` environment:

```
\renewenvironment{verbatim}
{\semiverbatim\small\color{blue}}
{\endsemiverbatim}
```

In case you want to change the color of `\verb` command, define a new command or redefine the original one as follows (requires package `newverbs`):

```
\newcommand{\myverb}{\collectverb{\small\color{blue}}}
\renewcommand{\verb}{\collectverb{\small\color{blue}}}
```